# spark-submit error : failed in initilizing sparkContext for non driver program vms

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

Cluster Specifications : Apache Spark on top of Mesos with 5 Vms and HDFS as storage.

***spark-env.sh***

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=192.168.xx.xxx #to set the IP address Spark binds to on this node
    enter code here`export MESOS_NATIVE_JAVA_LIBRARY="/home/xyz/tools/mesos-1.0.0/build/src/.libs/libmesos-1.0.0.so" #to point to your libmesos.so if you use Mesos
    export SPARK_EXECUTOR_URI="hdfs://vm8:9000/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz"
    HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/usr/local/tools/hadoop" #To point Spark towards Hadoop configuration files
```

**spark-defaults.conf**

```
spark.executor.uri  hdfs://vm8:9000/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
    spark.driver.host   192.168.xx.xxx
    spark.rpc       netty
    spark.rpc.numRetries    5
    spark.ui.port       48888
    spark.driver.port   48889
    spark.port.maxRetries   32
```

I did some experiments with submitting word-count scala application in cluster mode, I observed that it executes successfully  only when it finds driver program (containing main method) from the Vm it was submitted. As per my knowledge scheduling of resources (VMs) is handled by Mesos. for example if i submit my application from vm12 and coincidently if Mesos also schedules vm12 for executing application then it will execute successfully.In contrast it will fail if mesos scheduler decides to allocate let's say vm15.I checked logs in stderr of mesos UI and found error..

16/09/27 11:15:49 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.

Besides I tried looking for  configuration aspects of spark in following link.
[http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html][1] I tried setting rpc as it seemed necessary to keep driver program near to worker-node in LAN.
But couldn't get much insights.

I also tried uploading my code (application) in HDFS and submitting application jar file from HDFS.The same observations I received.

While connecting apache-spark with Mesos according to the documentation in
following link http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html
I also tried configuring spark-defaults.conf, spark-env.sh in other VM's in order to check if it successfully runs at least from 2 Vm's. That also didn't workout.

Am I missing any conceptual clarity here.?
So how can I make my application run successfully regardless of Vm's I'm submitting from ?

Comment: Have you started MesosClusterDispatcher?

Comment: @ImDarrenG Yeah I did start the MesosClusterDispatcher that enabled me to see output in MesosUI.